# allow disqus to show more then once on a same page

Tags: disqus

I want to show disqus commenting system more than once on a single page. For eg: there are 10 posts on a single page, so i want to load disqus 10 times, one for each post. Is it possible, I have no idea. I have added a disqus script that shows once on a page

Comment: same question has been asked and answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963505/several-disqus-threads-on-one-page/7401950#7401950