# Django + disqus: Comment options below every blog entry

Tags: django, comments, blogs, disqus, django-fluent

On my site, I am displaying multiple blog entries on one page. I would like to give the users the option to comment below every entry, but `django-disqus` is giving me a hard time.

In my **html template**, I am rotating through the blog entry items and want to display the comment option by `disqus` below:

```
...
{% load disqus_tags %}
{% disqus_dev %}  
...
{% for entry in blog %}
<div class="span5">
    <p>{{ entry.text }}</p> 
    {% set_disqus_identifier "entry_" entry.id %}
    {% disqus_recent_comments shortname 5 50 0 24 %} 
{% endfor %}    
...
```

However, Django is complaining with an error that

> Exception Type: AttributeError 
>   Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'var'

How can I display a dedicated comment field by `Disqus` for every blog entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to display multiple comment sections on the same page since `disqus` is using the `url` as identifier.

[There was a SO post regarding a similar implementation in JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963505/several-disqus-threads-on-one-page)

I have discarded `django-disqus` and implemented `django-fluent-comments` [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-comments). It seems to allow this specific requirement.

Simply add to your code:

```
...
{% load comments %}
...
{% render_comment_list for object %}
...
```

where `object` is your blog entry object.
That works for me as a solution.