# Embed Disqus multiple times (twice) on one page

Tags: javascript, php, html, embed, disqus

yes there is alread an answer to this question, but it is outdated, as disqus broke it in 2012:
[Several disqus-threads on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963505/several-disqus-threads-on-one-page)

I would like to use Disqus twice on one site. Because I compare two things and I want the user to be able to comment on both without mixing the comments.

Do you have any idea how this could be done at the end of 2013 ?

Iframes are not realy an option!

Comment: Is it possible to create a server-side Disqus loader that then gets included twice?

Comment: I think so, but I´m not sure.