# Disqus in Angular 2 application: Showing same discussion.

Tags: angular, disqus

I have Angular 2 app in there I use [ng2-awesome-disqus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-awesome-disqus) component.

On the page **I have several items and for each item I have one discussion** component :

```
<disqus [shortname]="shortname" [identifier]="identifier"></disqus>
```

- **shortname** is same for each item
- **identifier** is unique for each item

I would expect unique discussion for each item, but there are all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, disqus only allows a single widget per page. I think (actually, I'm sure), your module can only deal with one disqus widget. Take a look at the [code of the service](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ng2-disqus/blob/master/src/disqus.service.ts).

You have to fork this project and manage multiple widget by yourself or create your own component that will do that if possible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963505/several-disqus-threads-on-one-page) might help.

Answer (score -2):

For exam

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
   <disqus [shortname]="item.shortname" [identifier]="i"></disqus>
</ng-container>
```